# Is it possible to see comments from Gerrit plugin in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, plugins, ide, gerrit

I have installed the Gerrit plugin to Android Studio IDE. It is useful for the code review.

But when I have my commit and someone reviews it in Gerrit, I see in the plugin, that the comment is there.
But there is no way how to see what the comment actually says.

**Is there a way, how to see the content of these comments inside the Android Studio? (either by plugin or some other way)**

I suppose it I the same as IntelliJ IDEA, so answers based on that are also welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are ongoing activities to make this process a little better, more integrated into the editor:

https://github.com/uwolfer/gerrit-intellij-plugin/issues/243

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-138302

But yes, you can see which files has comments from Gerrit in the Gerrit plugin view, to the right.

[image: Comments from gerrit]

Right click file and choose Diff and you will find the comment in the diff view.

[image]

Mouse-over the "text" icon next to the line number to see the comment.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is also same for IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, but it actually doesn't answer my question. Do you know how can I see the content of the comments please?